# How to protect a pyramid registry from changes for tests?

Tags: python, pytest, pyramid

I'm trying to write sensible [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/) fixtures for testing large [pyramid](https://trypyramid.com/) applications.

One of the things I'm trying is to do to speed up test execution is to create the pyramid wsgi app as a [session fixture rather than a test fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html), as this creation is reasonably expensive and yet is needed by most tests.

But if any test messes with the app [registry](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/registry.html) in the mean time, the registry will remain polluted for the rest of the test run, and this kind of breakage is difficult to locate as it usually manifests as failures in some random tests in further down the same test run.

So I'd like to be able to either rollback changes to a registry on a fixture teardown or clone a pyramid registry on a fixture set up.

Bonus points if I can lock a registry to raise errors if anyone tries to change a locked down registry.

## Question

How do I make sure to always come back to the same pyramid registry while avoiding creating a new wsgi app at every test run?

Comment: I'm wondering what kind of tests you are trying to implement. For unit tests your setup is too complex and for any kind of high level test (intergration, behaviour, e2e...) I would consider the fact that one test disturbs the other a test failure.

Comment: @KlausD., This would be more like a pyramid-level integration test, and yes, one test disturbing another is an error. Still, just like on databases we can make tests that flush data and doesn't care to delete it if the test teardown itself can roll back the transaction, I'd like to have tooling that revert the registry to a known good state at the end/beginning of every test.

Answer (score 0):

The registry does not have a supported api for freezing itself. You could subclass it and override some methods to make it readonly-ish if you wanted but it's certainly a bit tedious. Things like setattr, registerUtility, etc.

Comment: That's what I figured by looking at the code, so I was hoping for an easy way to clone a registry...

Comment: a deep copy would be impossible - a shallow may be possible but I'm unaware of a public api for it

Comment: I'd be happy with a shallow copy.